# American citizens playing foreign sweepstakes

Tags: international, law, legal, lottery

I've read here: http://www.fraudaid.com/scamspam/lottery/foreign_lottery_federal_statute.htm that it is illegal for U.S. citizens to play foreign lotteries (although many Americans play the Canadian lotto, and many non-U.S. citizens play the U.S. lotto, so wtf?), however, is it illegal for U.S. citizens to play foreign *sweepstakes*? The difference between a lottery and a sweepstake being that to play a lottery, you **have** to pay to play, but sweepstakes are either completely free or require a free alternative method of entry next to the option with payment.

Now, of course, most of these are scams and whatnot, but let's say there is a genuine sweepstake in England organized by a certain company, where entry to the competition is either by paying or by the alternative and free method of applying by telephone/mail, etc.

Is it "illegal" for a U.S. citizen to participate in this foreign sweepstake, either by paying or by entering the competition by the alternative free method? Once again, there is a difference between a lottery (payment is necessary) and a sweepstake (payment is possible but not necessary), so does the law only apply for *lotteries* or sweepstakes as well?

If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: First time I hear such a claim. Since when US citizens are not allowed to buy lotto tickets outside of US? The link you provided doesn't provide any basis to its claim.

Comment: Well it's hard for me to decipher the "law-speak," but does the "18 U.S. Code § 1953 - Interstate transportation of wagering paraphernalia" not say precisely that? That's how I understood it at least, and that's why I'm asking whether sweepstakes are treated differently, because it's hard to decipher the law...

Comment: Here is another link where it says it is illegal to play foreign lotteries: https://www.michigan.gov/ag/0,4534,7-164-17337_20942-256173--,00.html

Still, is it illegal to play free foreign _sweepstakes_?

Comment: I found the answer on http://forums.online-sweepstakes.com/, it is **NOT** illegal for U.S. citizens to play foreign sweepstakes!

Comment: You misunderstood. It is not illegal to play foreign lotteries. It is illegal to do that via mail.

Comment: Due to possible misinterpretation of laws and regulations by individuals who setup websites or comment on blogs I suggest always going to a U.S government site like the Federal Trade Commission first to get answers. And don't forget that laws change, so some of what you read may be obsolete. On the FTC site, search for Lottery, Sweepstakes and Prizes. You'll find your answers there.

Comment: The claim on that website is without connection to the linked law - the law talks about 'Interstate transportation of wagering paraphernalia', and not about _participating_. To me it seems like it is a completely unfounded claim.

Comment: Apart from US law, you must also consider the laws of the host country and/or rules of any foreign lottery/sweepstake you consider participating in. For example, the UK National Lottery requires players to be physically located in the UK when playing.

Answer (score 2):

It is not illegal to play a foreign lottery, or for a foreigner to play in the US lottery.

What is illegal (at least according to the statute you linked to) is to buy it across the State border. I.e.: you can buy a lottery ticket in an English lottery - when you're physically in England. You cannot buy it via mail/email/phone/whatever else method where you're not actually physically present there. You cannot, also, bring that ticket back with you. It has to stay in England, and you have to cash it in England if you won. You can bring the winnings back (declaring them properly, obviously).

I would say sweepstakes be treated like a lottery ticket, for the purpose of this law (it's a lottery essentially, a game of numbers).

I am not an attorney, and this is my understanding of this law.

Answer (score 0):

The claim on that website is without connection to the law it links to - the law bill talks about '**Interstate transportation of wagering paraphernalia**', and not in any way about *participating* in a lottery. To me it seems like it is a completely unfounded claim.

You *should* be worried if you plan to *transport* Canadian lottery tickets *across the US*, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

'Interstate' means precisely that - between US states, not 'International' as in between nations. If US lawmakers cannot use the English language to convey the meanings they wish - it is not the duty of the public to comply with their mistakes.

Comment: However, *ignorantia juris non excusat* (ignorance of the law is no excuse).